# No really, when does floating point promotion actually happen?

Tags: c++, floating-point, promotions

From this other [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215484/floating-point-promotion-stroustrup-vs-compiler-who-is-right) they talk about how Bjarne Stroustrup said that just as integral data-types narrower than an `int`(e.g. `short`) are promoted to an `int`, `float`s are promoted to a `double`. However, unlike widening of integrals narrower than an `int`, ***floating point promotion*** does not happen in the same way, but instead, occurs elsewhere.

I know that if you were to compute `float + double` the `float` would be converted to a `double` before the binary operator(`+`) is applied. However, this is not ***floating point promotion*** according to [Learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-implicit-type-conversion-coercion/). This is ***usual arithmetic conversion***.

When does floating point promotion actually happen?

Comment: read through the comments and answers you'll see the Bjarne's book is in error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [floating-point promotion : stroustrup vs compiler - who is right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215484/floating-point-promotion-stroustrup-vs-compiler-who-is-right)

Comment: @RichardHodges I've read through the comments. Even if that small excerpt was taken out of the book, that does not tell me if floating point promotion was taken out of the language. I still have no idea of when floating point promotion can occur.

Comment: This thread is also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097564/why-does-printf-promote-a-float-to-a-double

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is such a thing as "floating point promotion" of `float` to `double` per [conv.fpprom].

> A prvalue of type `float` can be converted to a prvalue of type `double`. The value is unchanged.
>
> This conversion is called *floating point promotion.*

The answers to the linked question are correct. This promotion should not occur automatically when adding two `float`s since the usual arithmetic conversions do not promote floating-point operands.

Floating point promotion *does* occur when passing a `float` as an operand to an ellipsis, like in `printf`. That's why the `%f` format specifier prints either a `float` or a `double`: if you pass a `float`, the function actually receives a `double`, the result of promotion.

The existence of the floating point promotion is also important in overload resolution, because integral *promotions* and floating point *promotions* have better implicit conversion rank than integral *conversions*, floating point *conversions*, and floating-integral *conversions*.

Example 1:

```
void f(double);
void f(long double);
f(0.0f);
```

This calls `void f(double)` since the promotion to `double` is better than the conversion to `long double`. In contrast, consider this perhaps surprising example 2:

```
void f(long double);
void f(int);
f(0.0f);
```

This is ambiguous. The conversion from `float` to `long double` is no better than the conversion from `float` to `int` since they are both not promotions.

Example 3:

```
struct S {
    operator float();
    operator int();
};
double d = S();
```

This calls `operator float` and then promotes the resulting `float` value to `double` to initialize `d`.

Comment: Your answer is so detailed and has great examples. I completely get floating point promotion now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't float to long double a "promotion" as opposed to "conversion"?

Answer (score 7):

The primary (perhaps sole) time that floating point promotions are applied is when passing an argument to a variadic function (e.g., `printf`).

In this case, the usual arithmetic conversions don't apply (they're for finding a common type between two operands in an expression).

The relevant part of the standard is [expr.call]/7 (at least as of N4296):

> When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking va_arg (18.10).
>   
> [...]
>   If the argument has integral or enumeration type that is subject to the integral promotions (4.5), or a floating point type that is subject to the floating point promotion (4.6), the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call.

Comment: Are you talking about type conversion? I know that type conversion happens if you pass a float to a variadic function that has a double as it's parameter. I don't believe type conversion and floating point promotion are the same thing. If you meant something else, will you please elaborate?

Comment: Oh! You're talking about ellipses. Where the parameter could be any value and any number of values. So that's where floating point promotion can happen. Thank you!