# Why cannot floating-point promotion work for arithmetics as well?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have read a bit about floating-point promotion. I know that it doesn't apply on binary arithmetic operations, only on e.g. overload resolution. But why?

The C++ standard guarantees that double must be at least as precise as float [basic.fundamental.8] and the floating point promotion is required to keep the value unchanged [conv.fpprom]. Yet [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490592/no-really-when-does-floating-point-promotion-actually-happen) makes it very clear that it does not happen. Stroustrup, 4th edition has the subject even errata-ed ([here](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html), Chapter 10, p. 267).

However, I cannot see any reason why the promotion cannot be done in *usual arithmetic conversions* [expr.10], even if all prerequisites are met. Is there any?

The latest C++14 working draft can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), the final version is purchase-only.

Comment: `usual arithmetic conversions [expr.10]` can you post a link or something which describe this usual conversion so that not every reader has to find it by himself?

Comment: @UmNyobe I added link to the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a `float` to a `double` costs something, and it's likely more expensive than a `short` to `int` conversion (it needs several shifts and bit combining operations). And unlike e.g. `short`, the `float` type is considered something on which the processor can operate directly (just like it can on `int`).

Given the facts obove, why *should* floating-point promotion happen when it's not necessary? That is, if you're adding two `float`s, why convert them to `double`, add them, and then convert them back to `float`?<sup>(1)</sup>

Note that a floating-point promotion will indeed happen when you're adding mixed arguments (e.g. a `float + double`), by the very ruling in C++14 [expr] you're referring to.

> - (10.3) Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.

As per [conv.fpprom], this conversion from `float` to `double` is carried out by *floating point promotion.*

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Of course, it is perfectly possible this will happen internally if the processor cannot operate on `float`s directly, and [expr].12 explicitly allows that. But that very paragraph says

> the types are not changed thereby.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am having trouble finding out where exactly is floating-point promotion allowed in [expr]. All I can find is conversion (10.3). Under IEEE 754 this is lossless, but perhaps some other floating-point implementation can distinguish between promotion and conversion.

Comment: @JakubZaverka But converting a `float` to a `double` **is** a *floating point promotion.* Refer to 4.6

Comment: Oh I get it now, the conversion is done by promotion. I thought these are two separate operations that cannot be mixed together.

Answer (score 1):

**It does!**

I don't know what you call *"work"*, but the scope of definition for *floating-point promotion* and *usual arithmetic conversions* is different.

1. usual arithmetic conversions :  Apply to binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.
2. floating-point promotion : Apply to prvalues of type float.

Some expressions, like `a + b` qualify for both, while `1.0f` qualify only as a `prvalue`.

The standard you linked says (about `usual arithmetic conversions`)

> (10.3) if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to
>   double
>   
> ...
>   
> (10.5) — Otherwise, the **integral** promotions shall be performed on both operands

It doesn't ***restrict*** how the other operand is converted to double, so I would assume that `double + float` follow the `floating-point promotion` rule.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the distinction had to be made because of the difference between promotion and conversion. But if double is at least as precise as float, then indeed the conversion can also be lossless.